# Is it a new style progress bar for C#?

Tags: .net, progress-bar

VS2012 is using some trendy flying dots during the update installation.

[image]

Is it a progress bar and available for .NET (WinForms or WPF)?

Comment: In this case there are both progress bars above. But the `ProgressBar` class also contains the stye `Marquee` scrolling endless.

Comment: It can be just an image?

Comment: It is custom.  Modeled after Windows 8 progress animations.  Most likely driven by a Storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called `ProgressIndicator` and is one of the Metro GUI components of Windows 8. The  [MahApps.Metro](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro) project demonstares how it works.